# Size of a dynamic std array

Tags: c++, size

I am quite new in C++ and at some point I try to figure out how to measure the size of a dynamic array. To be more specific lets say I define:

```
std::vector<int> dirichNodes;
```

and then after some operations I filled that vector. Later I would like to see its entries like:

```
    for (int i=0; i<????(size of dirichNodes vector); i++)
{

std::cout<<dirichNodes[i]<<std::endl;

}
```

what i would like to know is what to insert in the place of ???? here.

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you need to look for a good [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vector::size() will return the number of elements in a vector.

```
for (int i=0; i<dirichNodes.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout<<dirichNodes[i]<<std::endl;    
}
```

Comment: A more idiomatic way would be to use a [ranged based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) or use [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin)